# Queremos Stack Snippets

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, stack-snippets

Noté que no hay stack snippets.
(no está el botón para insertar code snippets para JavaScript).

[image: No está el botón]

---

- [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) los tiene [image: en portugués]
- [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) los tiene [image: en ruso]
- [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) los tiene [image: en japonés]

---

¿Fue una omisión por error? ¿Se decidió no implementarlos momentáneamente? ¿O es un punto pendiente en el que se está trabajando?

Me interesaría verlos implementados acá.

Comment: Si definitivamente espero que se implemente o active pronto

Answer (score 13, accepted):

¡Los stack snippets se implementarán hoy!

Comment: Esto debe de estar en vivo ya. :)

Comment: ... Y funcionando perfectamente. Muchísimas gracias Juan, Jon Ericson y al equipo de desarrollo!